# laravel eloquent relationship hierarchy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, hierarchy

I seem to be having a problem understanding this hierarchical relationship.

Farm > Fields > Shepherds > Sheep

It seems a pretty straightforward hierarchy - Farm hasMany fields, field hasMany shepherds, shepherd hasMany sheep.

Sheep belong to a shepherd, shepherds belongs to fields, fields belong to farms.

I have defined this model relationships thus:

```
class Sheep extends Model {

    protected $fillable ['name'];

    public function shepherd() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Shepherd');
        }    
}


class Shepherd extends Model {

    protected $fillable ['name'];

    public function field() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Field');
        }    
    public function sheep() {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Sheep');
    }               
}

class Field extends Model {

    protected $fillable ['name'];

    public function farm() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Farm');
        }    

    public function shepherd() {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Shepperd');
    }   
}

class Farm extends Model {

    protected $fillable ['name'];

    public function field() {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Field');
        }    
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('farms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('farm_id');
        $table->string('name');
    });
}
public function up()
    Schema::create('shepherds', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('field_id');
        $table->string('name');
    });
}
public function up()
    Schema::create('sheep', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('shepherd_id');
        $table->string('name');
    });
}
```

I would expect to be able to save each model in the following manner.

```
$farm = new App\Farm;

$farm->name = 'West Farm';

$field = new App\Field;

$field->name = 'The orchard';

$shepherd = new App\Shepherd;

$shepherd->name = 'Jason';

$sheep = new App\Sheep;

$sheep->name = 'Sean';

$farm->save();

$farm->field()->save($farm);

$farm->field->shepherd()->save($shepherd);

$farm->field->shepherd->sheep()->save($sheep);
```

But it does not work. Once I get to `$farm->field->shepherd()->save($shepherd);` the process breaks down. I would appreciate some assistance in the correct manner of saving using the relationships between all the tables.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to understand this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: can you please add some info like errors, expected output / real output, etc?

Comment: The error I get is as follows - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::shepherd(). This occurs when i try   $farm->field->shepherd()->save($shepherd). But if I try $field->shepherd()->save($shepherd) then that works, why can't I do $farm->field->shepherd()->save($shepherd)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code breaks here:

```
$farm->field->shepherd()->save($shepherd);
```

Farms have many fields, so when you reference **$farm->field**, you're getting a collection of **Field** object, not just a single **Field** object.

To make it work, you need to either reference **$farm->field[0]**

```
$farm->field[0]->shepherd()->save($shepherd);
```

or just use the **$field** object you created before:

```
$field->shepherd()->save($shepherd);
```

I'd also suggest to use plural names for your **hasMany** relations (fields, sheeps, etc.) - this way you'll always remember that the referenced fields refer to a collection, not a single object

Comment: OK, I think I am getting my logic backwards. I can say $sheep->shepherd->field->farm because each reference is to a single item. Is it then possible to define all of my objects $sheep, $shepherd, $field, $farm and save them with one single function so that all the relationships are created?

Comment: Yes. Once you set relations properly you can call push() instead of save() - it will call save() on current model AND push() on all relations, which in turn will call save() on all related models AND push() on all their relations etc...